# Problem with the preview in the ioslides presentation

Tags: r-markdown, ioslides

I am using the ioslides_presentation output. I have some latex code. In my preview (after knitting), I always see a return before each latex symbol. As the following shows
[image]
If I view it in the browser, it is perfectly fine
[image]

What is wrong with my preview? How should I set it up as the view in the browser?
I attach the source code and compiling report. Thank you!

```
---
title: "Bla Bla "
subtitle: "sss"
author: "Joey"
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), format="%B %d, %Y")`'
output:
  ioslides_presentation
---

## 
 If $\alpha\in[\frac{1}{8},1)\backslash \{1/3\}$, then a shrinker of ?? is a shrinking circle.
 If $\alpha=\frac{1}{3}$, then a shrinker is a shrinking ellipsoid. 
 If $\alpha \in (0,\frac{1}{8})$, then a shrinker is a circle 
 or a curve ${\Gamma_{\alpha}^k}$ with $k$-fold symmetry,
```

```
  |......................................................................| 100%
   inline R code fragments


/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to html4 --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output test.html --email-obfuscation none --self-contained --variable transition=0.4 --template /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/ioslides/default.html --include-in-header /var/folders/yb/7mjccgyj7sg0_04sv3pxnnxc0000gn/T//Rtmpo5qpXF/rmarkdown-str501875693231.html --mathjax --variable 'mathjax-url:https://mathjax.rstudio.com/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML' 
output file: test.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS test.utf8.md --to ioslides_presentation.lua --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output /var/folders/yb/7mjccgyj7sg0_04sv3pxnnxc0000gn/T//Rtmpo5qpXF/ioslides-output50184d5e6b2f.html --slide-level 2 

Output created: test.html
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this; looks the same in RStudio preview and Chrome (I'm on MacOS, too).

Comment: I tried updating the Pandoc and R. It still the same thing. Thank you for your reply anyway.